# On discouraging "let me repeat that" answers

Tags: discussion

I've noticed several instances lately, though I suspect it has always been the case, that someone will give a new answer that adds nothing new. The worst cases are when someone just gives a subset of the recommendations of an earlier answer. The new answer is just a bit of noise. Sometimes it will be ideas from several answers, but still, nothing new.

*I wonder if it is desirable and possible to "discourage" such posts without seeming too heavy handed.*

One possibility would just be some advice in the help pages. Not every new user seems to get the point that this site isn't just a bunch of discussion threads. That may be related.

We have mechanisms already in voting and comments for people to express agreement with the advice in an existing answer.

---

[Here is an example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/180262/75368) of this. Another user posted while I was writing. This has happened a couple of times. (Rep needed to see my deleted answer.)

Comment: Near duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered

Answer (score 6):

I downvote answers as "not helpful" if they are nothing but a superficial repeat of existing answers, especially when they are particularly low-effort. However, it's worth taking care that sometimes there are multiple ways to say the same thing, and some of those ways can be better than others. That can include answers that are *brief and direct*, even when other answers provide more context and detail. Synthesizing multiple other answers into one answer can also be useful. I've frequently added my own answer to a question that's more or less the same as other answers but I feel needs to be more clear on a key point.

Mods can "protect" questions to prevent no-rep users from answering; often HNQ-featured questions get this protection (though it isn't supposed to be a reason to protect by itself, HNQ tends to go hand-in-hand with the reasons a question *should* be protected) which helps avoid these answers. [High rep users can also protect questions (with a couple limiting criteria)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-or-highly-active-question), and I think you can be fairly loose with this option when it is available to you and you're seeing people chime in with non-answer answers.

If an answer consists of "I agree with Buffy's answer, but (wanted to make a side comment or contribute to discussion)", you can flag as "not an answer" and it will likely be converted to a comment or removed. Answers should stand on their own, and while it's fine to reference other answers in your own answer, it shouldn't be necessary to *read* other answers to get to a complete one. Feel free to flag outright plagiarism of other answers, as well (better to use a custom flag for that so a moderator knows what to look for); these can be machine-automated attempts at gathering rep to use for spam or other nefarious purposes.

Comment: How about "let me repeat that" as a descriptive?

Comment: @Buffy Sounds good to me. I don't think the original was wrong, either, just didn't want it to lead to confusion. I had trouble searching MSE for broader guidance on this issue because it's interlocked with the other one there.

Comment: I generally limit downvotes to posts I think are actually harmful if the advice is taken. I've been (a bit) tempted to comment on the "repeat.." answers asking "why bother", but feel it is a bit too negative. But somewhat experienced users also do this on occasion.

Answer (score 4):

> One possibility would just be some advice in the help pages

The best help page to give this piece of advice would probably be in [How do I write a good answer?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) However, this page is the same network-wide and not customizable by site moderators. Within the pages that are customizable, I don't see a good place for that addition. Furthermore, help pages are likely only read after someone points out issues with a post.

About what to do, I agree with [Bryan's answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5077/20058), but let me stress that flagging could be particularly useful in case of repeated instances from the same user, so that in case we can advise them with a moderator message.

Comment: Notice how in the last paragraph I'm doing exactly what the OP wants to discourage :-p

Comment: Actually, I often do something similar when I think an answer has many good points but needs additional advice. As you do here, I link to the question I want to extend rather than just phrasing it as "an earlier answer" or similar. But, also as you do here, there was a new element. On at least one occasion I got more rep than the answer I pointed to, but that wasn't the intention. In fact, such linking can, I hope, boost the answer linked as well as making it obvious and easy to find. So, this isn't what I really mean. It is answers that really don't add anything.

Comment: Pointing to a help page after the fact might actually be a benefit, even if not the main page. Better than a personal complaint to a writer, I think.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano For what it's worth, the general guidance is that for this sort of thing Meta should be treated differently than main sites, so you're forgiven this time :)